# PHP Generate Ascii file?

Tags: php, csv, ascii

I am generating a CSV file but the people who are processing these file tells me it needs to be in ASCII format??  How do I go about to make that?

This is what I have to generate the file:

```
$filename = '/logs/'.date('Ymd').'.txt';
$myfile = fopen($filename,'a');
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

This file generates fine and opens fine...everything is ok to the naked eye but they said it needs to be in ascii format...

Output of file:

```
"","932-4","Mike","Tanner","","1234 Testing Lane","","Los Angeles","CA","90066","","(993)857-7727","","","","SALE","","","V","4111111111111111","01/14","AXLW","","ZENC","","","REG","","511.80","","07/21/11","932-359","D1234","4","","1","","","","","","","Tanner","Mike","","1234 Testing Lane","","CA","Los Angeles","90066","","CC","","","","Y","100.00","","100.00","","","","","","","","Y","11.8","info@info.com","359","001","001","(993)857-7727","(993)857-7727","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","222","","","","","","","","","","","","","",
```

Anyone?

Thanks...

Comment: can you ask them what is exactly that is wrong with your file?

Comment: Can you post some sample output?

Comment: I added the output...They didn't say specifically what is wrong but they just said it cannot be ANSI, it must be ASCII...They are opening it up in Windows system and I am generating this with PHP so I am on unix/linux box..maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Do you have a hex editor? If so, open your result file. If it shows one byte per character, it's ASCII.

Comment: @Jonathan: not so. ASCII uses only seven bits of a byte. If the high bit is set, it's not ASCII.

Comment: I dont have a hex editor so I cant see...perhaps my question should be how to write carriage return that works on both windows/pc and linux/unix

Comment: @Michael, yes, but even with multibyte encodings like utf-8, if it's one character per byte, it conforms to ascii.

Comment: @Jonathan: that confuses the issue. It's possible to have a single byte per character, and not be ASCII. It's likely the OP is using some non-Unicode, non-ASCII encoding like Windows-1252.

Comment: @Michael: I understand your point. But the result data he gave had no 8-bit characters, and in that case, even Windows-1252 is identical to ASCII.

Comment: @Jonathan: sure. I highly doubt that the text listed above represents the entire contents of his file, though.

Comment: Actually that is the actual output..I just listed 1 line...actually there are 2 lines...But they are indentical lines...

Comment: @Rick: Any umlauts or other non-keyboard characters in your file? If so, to Michael's point, that's what they're complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to play [Carnac the Magnificent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnac_the_Magnificent) and say that you're just using a line-feed (ascii 10, aka \n) to terminate each line. I'll bet they want carriage-return plus line-feed (ascii 13,10). Just a wild guess. :)

Comment: @Rick, it's \r\n (CRLF) under Windows :)

Comment: @freedompeace: That would certainly make a difference to the processing house.

Comment: @Rick: per freedompeace's comment, try \r\n.

Comment: Yeah turns out I swapped \n\r...should have been \r\n...doh!!

Answer (score 1):

ANSI = Windows-1252, so probably: `$data = iconv("windows-1252","ASCII",$data);`